# scala, swing : make a table scroll to the last row non empty

Tags: scala, swing, scroll

I would like to be able to add a row in a table, to achieve this I thought to a button near the table, with the caption "New/Update". if no row is selected, then clicking on this button makes the table "scroll" to display the first empty row, then the person enter the informations in this row, and a second click on the button stores the new row.
But I need to make the table scroll, how can I do this?
I searched on internet and found this : [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0291.html), but it is in Java and I did not find the scala equivalent to getCellRect method.

please note I did not used a model for the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's a method that isn't implemented in the Scala version, you can use `peer` to access the underlying Java Swing version.

So you should be able to access the method in your question, if you have a `Table` `t`, using `t.peer.getCellRect`.